# fullscreen div scrolling to next page ruby rails?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, scroll

I posted a same question yesterday but realised my question was too vague?

basically this is how i want my code to work - i want a fullscreen div scrolling/ and when i click 'down' i want it to scroll down to my next fullscreen div

My code works - but it doesn't 'scroll' down ? and I'm not sure why.

Could anyone help?

the jquery code i was using is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('.tile a').click(function(event) {
var id = $(this).attr("href");

 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target}, 10000);
 event.preventDefault();
 });
 });
 </script>
```

css code

```
body,html {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}


.tile {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.tile div {
padding-top: 70px;
}

#up {
 background-color: #222;
 }
```

and my .erb code

```
<%## scroll up page ##%>
<div class='tile' id='up'>
<%## search bar ##%>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->


<div class=but_down style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red;"> 
<a href="#down"> down </a> 
</div>
</div>
<%## scroll down page ##%>
 <div class='tile' id='down'>
 <h1> yeah </h1>
 </div>
```

and i already know 
http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/

but i'm really, REALLY new to programming and not sure how to translate that 
code to ruby rails.

Could someone please help?

Comment: As you're new to programming, it's clear there's a key fact you have missed in terms of web programming. Ruby is server side (back end). It generates html which is sent to the client side (front end). You're asking how you can manipulate the front end with Ruby. You don't, you use Javascript (of which jQuery is a library).

Comment: yes i see that i have to use Javascript - which i DId use. I thought it was possible to use Jquery or Javascript with ruby..? (I have seen some people do that- ).  the first code in my question is javascript(as far as I know) and I wanted it to affect my .erb files..?

Comment: Again, you're still confused as to what's happning here. erb files are template files that your Ruby code compiles to html and javascript which is sent to the client (browser). Ruby will create text. Once the compiled text is sent to the client, you use javascript. The two do not interact at run time.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is, your question is completely unrelated to Ruby. So rather than showing us your templates, show the resulting html that the template creates.